# Why does ary.each dump out all of the contents of an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

foo is an array of objects, bar is an attribute of that object.

```
(rdb:1) foo.bar.map{|v| bar.v }
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]


(rdb:1) foo.bar.each{|v| p bar.v }
[massive outpouring of object attributes]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the result of `each` is defined to be the Enumerable object being iterated over.

If you want to use `each` in irb and not get swamped with output, then:

```
foo.bar.each{|v| p bar.v }; nil
```

Answer (score 1):

`#each` will return its receiver, and then irb will decide to helpfully print it, since [irb *is* a REPL.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)

You could just tack a `.any?` on the end of the expression:

```
(rdb:1) foo.bar.each{|v| p bar.v }.any?
# output from only the #p call
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to tell IRB not to display return values. That'd solve your problem without having to put `; nil` at the end of each line.

Alternatively, you could modify the `inspect` method of the `bars` so that it's less verbose.

```
class Bar
  def inspect
    "tl;dr"
  end
end
```